# Laravel tntsearch-driver can not installed

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, php-ini, php-curl

Below is my composer.json file

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "^1.18",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.9.2",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^3.0",
        "laravel/scout": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

I want to install tntsearch-driver for laravel scout but give error `To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:`
[image]

My php version is 7.0

i already tried sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl but not helpful for me.
and when trying to check curl version by curl-v give me error curl: no URL specified!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tntsearch need to open sqlite and pdo extension, you can use php -m to see if there are two extensions.
I guess you did not open sqlite extension.

Answer (score 0):

We can install `pdo_ sqlite`

if you are using php5 then `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite`,

if you are using php7 then `sudo apt-get install php7-sqlite`